# Esp32 at command customization method

Tags: esp32

I want to use AT command with separate coding in esp32 at Arduino IDE. However, if you flash AT command firmware and upload another code from Arduinoide, the existing at command will not be available. Is there a way to use it together?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking doesn't make any sense. The ESP32 can run a single program that's stored in its flash memory. It's not capable of running two firmware images at the same time. If it's running the AT firmware, it's not running an Arduino program, and vice versa.

You also do not need to talk to the AT firmware from an Arduino program running on the ESP32; the Arduino program is capable of directly doing much more than the AT firmware offers.

You might possibly be able to build a single firmware image that included both the AT firmware and an Arduino program, but it would be a great deal of work and would likely never work well if at all. Most of the AT firmware is released as compiled binaries, not source, so you would have little chance of customizing it or making it work in a hybrid environment.

You'd be much better off to reconsider why you think you need to do this and find a better solution.